# How to compile any swift file in a given folder?

Tags: swift, xcode

I use actual folders for my Xcode projects containing my `.swift` files. I dragged the folder into Xcode but it appears that my swift classes are not being built. I went to my target, went to *Build Phase*, went to *Compile Source* and added the missing folder to the references to be built.

My *swift* files are still not being built.

Which flag could I add to the folder (in Compile Source) for force it to compile every `.swift` files within it (including the ones in subfolders) ?

I couldn't find any info about it so far, any ideas ?

Comment: Are the files added to target? Xcode doesn't compile directories, it compiles files.

Comment: Oh I see now that the files in questions don't have a Target Membership tab on the right, how can I add that if my files are already in my Xcode file tree ?

Comment: Open the right side panel, click on every file and set the membership. Or remove all file references and add them again, selecting the target membership.

Comment: I don't have the _Target Membership_ section for those files in the right side panel though

Comment: Did you create a folder reference or a group? Don't create folder references, remove them and add the directory again, creating a group.

Comment: I used a folder reference, thanks I'll try importing as a group

Comment: @Sulthan thanks it worked by adding everything as _groups_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR** Use *Groups*, not *Folder References*.

*Folder References* in Xcode are made mainly for resources. When you create a folder reference, Xcode won't care about the contents. They are helpful when copying resources that should keep their directory structure.

To organize source code files, you need *Groups*. Groups are logical project folders and most of the time they are backed up by a file system folder anyway.

See also [Difference between folder and group in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207664/difference-between-folder-and-group-in-xcode)